# Why is my Discord bot always speak its message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I type in any commands in discord, my bot always says :
`Trietrobotvjp said ...` (my bot name "Trietrobotvjp"), and all users in guild can also hear that.
This is so annoying! Can anyone help me fix it ?
This is an example of one of my commands :

```
@client.command()
@cooldown(1,4,BucketType.user)
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Current latency: **{round(client.latency * 1000)}** ms')
```

I tried to put in `tts = False` but it isn't work.
And the bot always speak all of its commands.
Sorry for bad English

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed by reinstall `discord.py` and `discord-components`

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to fix. It means you have "Send Text-to-Speech Messages" on for the bot, or all users. It's a permission and doesn't have anything to do with your code itself.

[image: Picture]

Comment: But how can I fix if I can't change the permission settings ? Because my bot is a public bot so I can't always do that myself

Comment: Well almost nobody has that enabled as it drives you crazy if you do. I personally never had this problem, or ever heard of it.